# How can I remove First[{}] from the output list of a function?

Tags: replacement, filtering, core-language

Consider:

```
listOfKeys = {"Ambientalismo", "Anoressia"};
list2 = First /@ (WikidataSearch /@ listOfKeys)
```

I've tried

```
Replace[list2, First[{}] :> Missing["NotFound"]]
```

and I was also trying to use:

```
Select[list2, Not[First[]]]
```

But they are both wrong. What should I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the two-argument form of `First`:

> [image]

```
listOfKeys = {"Ambientalismo", "Anoressia", "blahblah"};

list3 =First[#,  Missing["NotFound"]]&/@ (WikidataSearch /@ listOfKeys)
```

[image]

```
DeleteMissing[list3]
```

> [image]

**Update:** Re ***"just to understand why my attempt are not working"***  and ***"if I have a list with {1, "anoressia", First[{}] } and I want to use Replace or Select to delete the last element"***:

```
lista = Quiet @ {1, "anoressia", First[{}]}
```

> ```
> {1, "anoressia", First[{}]}
> ```

Wrap the pattern `First[{}]` with [`HoldPattern`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldPattern.html) to prevent evaluation of `First[{}]` (which returns `First[{}]` with an error message):

```
Replace[lista, HoldPattern[First[{}]] -> Missing["NotFound"], All]
```

> {1, "anoressia", Missing["NotFound"]}

```
lista /. HoldPattern[First[{}]] -> Missing["NotFound"]
```

> {1, "anoressia", Missing["NotFound"]}

```
Cases[lista, Except[_First]]
```

> {1, "anoressia"}

```
Cases[lista, Except[HoldPattern @ First[{}]]]
```

> {1, "anoressia"}

Using [`DeleteCases`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DeleteCases.html) and [`Select`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Select.html):

```
DeleteCases[lista, _First]
```

> {1, "anoressia"}

```
Select[lista, Head[#] =!= First &]
```

> {1, "anoressia"}

```
Select[lista, Not @* MatchQ[_First]]
```

> ```
> {1, "anoressia"}
> ```

Comment: Thanks. Do you know a way to "recover" the output (just to understand why my attempt are not working)

Comment: @Revious, `DeleteMissing[list2]`?

Comment: if I have a list with {1, "anoressia", First[{}] } and I want to use Replace or Select to delete the last element

Comment: @Revious, please see the update.

Comment: really thanks a lot!